# Веб сервер на python

Tags: python

Хочу сделать некий веб ресурс, который будет иметь простейшее API, с ответом в виде json. В ответе должны прилетать данные из базы данных. Собственно в чем моя проблема: данные в базе данных должны обновляться. То-есть...Сервер должен работать и отвечать на запросы клиентов, но при этом, постоянно должен мониторить другие ресурсы и парсить с них информацию, которую собственно и будет сохранять в БД. Я не совсем понимаю, что для создания такого ресурса нужно использовать, и может ли сервер выполнять какие-то фоновые задачи по парсингу и "общаться" с клиентами ОДНОВРЕМЕННО?

Comment: ОДНОВРЕМЕННО - нет. Yо может паралельно(threads) и конкурентно(asyncio). Но рекомендую запустить 2 сервера, каждый из которых выполняет свю задачу.

Comment: Получается 2 сервера работают с одной БД?

Comment: да, их может быть и больше.

Comment: А что по поводу сущности, которая будет отвечать за обновление данных в БД. Это лучше написать в виде скрипта, сервера что лучше?

Comment: преодические задачи в планировщик, а уж где он будет внутри или снаружи - вам решать